# The easiest way to implement a barchart with 2 columns using apache poi and ooxml-schemas

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi, openxml

I'm trying to create n bar chart of 2 columns in a xlsx file like below.

[image]

But It's so confuse to me , to understand how the class inside the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart` works.

I've already tryied but the generate file does not get the chart that I have drawed.

I have this code:

```
        Drawing drawing = planilha.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 15);

        Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

        CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart();
        CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
        CTBarChart ctBarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewBarChart();
        CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctBarChart.addNewVaryColors();
        ctBoolean.setVal(true);
        ctBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.COL);

           CellRangeAddress rangeAreas =  new CellRangeAddress(1,3,1,1);
        CellRangeAddress rangeTotais = new CellRangeAddress(1,3,5,5);

        CTBarSer ctBarSer = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
        CTSerTx ctSerTx = ctBarSer.addNewTx();
        CTStrRef ctStrRef = ctSerTx.addNewStrRef();
        ctStrRef.setF("Gráfico!"+rangeAreas.formatAsString());

        CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewVal();
        CTNumRef ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumRef();
        ctNumRef.setF("Gráfico!"+rangeTotais.formatAsString());
        //this code below I copied of an example and I don't know what is necessary 
        ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456);
        ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457);

        CTCatAx ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx(); 
        ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
        CTScaling ctScaling = ctCatAx.addNewScaling();
        ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
        ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
        ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
        ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
        ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

        CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx(); 
        ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
        ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
        ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
        ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
        ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
        ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
        ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apache poi 4.0.0`, the last stable version, creating bar charts is possible without using the low level underlying beans. For this [Package org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/package-summary.html) is used.

Some parts of the `XDDF` stuff are buggy until now. So we need to repair something. But nevertheless we should using those classes rather than the low level underlying beans.

Example for your requirement:

Source:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.PresetColor;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFShapeProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFSolidFillProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrosses;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrossBetween;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFCategoryAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFValueAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelBarChartFromExistingData {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Workbook.xlsx"))) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
      legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

      // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
      XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
      XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
      leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
      leftAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

      XDDFDataSource<String> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, 3, 1, 1));
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, 3, 5, 5));

      XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
      data.addSeries(xs, ys);
      chart.plot(data);

      //Since XDDF stuff is buggy until now, we need to repair something.

      //repairing set the kind of bar char, either bar chart or column chart:
      if (chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getBarDir() == null) 
       chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).addNewBarDir();
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getBarDir().setVal(
       org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STBarDir.COL);
       //org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STBarDir.BAR);

      //repairing telling the axis Ids in bar chart:
      if (chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getAxIdList().size() == 0) {
       chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(bottomAxis.getId());
       chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(leftAxis.getId());
      }

      //repairing no Tx when there is no title
      if (chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getTx() != null)
       chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getBarChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).unsetTx();

      XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(PresetColor.BLUE));
      XDDFChartData.Series firstSeries = data.getSeries().get(0);
      XDDFShapeProperties properties = firstSeries.getShapeProperties();
      if (properties == null) {
        properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
      }
      properties.setFillProperties(fill);
      firstSeries.setShapeProperties(properties);

      // Write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("WorkbookNew.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

To answer your implicit question how to understand the classes inside the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart`:

To get this known we need knowing how `Excel` stores it's data. The `*.xlsx` files are simply `ZIP` archives. So we can simply unzip them and having a look into.

There we find `XML` files. For charts `/xl/charts/chart1.xml` for example. Now first we need understanding that  `XML`.

Then we need information about the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart` package. We can download [ooxml-schemas-1.4-sources.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/) and then doing `javadoc` of this. Now we have a `API` documentation for all the underlying beans inclusive package `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart`.

Comment: Hi Axel . I'm really thankfull for your answer, but I'm still getting an error.
About a class : `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;`

Comment: Do using [XmlBeans » 3.0.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/3.0.1) as also mentioned in [Apache poi Component Map](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components). Make sure you do not have other versions of `xmlbeans` in class path.

Comment: Is there another package to download? I've dowloaded the xml beans 3.0.1 as you said . But now the errors changed . I'm getting this : `SEVERE: Resource read error: Could not load org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/values/XmlComplexContentImpl.class.
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)` my JRE is 1.6 Would it be the problem?

Comment: Hi Axel with the xmlbeans 3.0.2 it worked.
I'm really thankfull.